# Use formulas to select chart data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large data table with a number of different measurements and parameters.  I am trying to create a number of charts that organize the data series based on the parameters.  For example, if I had data like this:

```
    Xval    Yval    ParA    ParB
    22      5       10      0.25
    27      7       10      0.5
    26      6       20      0.25
    25      8       20      0.5
```

I might want to create two charts - one that has a series for each value of ParA, and one that has a series for each value of ParB.  What I want to do is be able to define the series data forumlaicly, saying something like (sudocode)

```
Series1x = Xval, IF(ParA==10)
Series1y = Yval, IF(ParA==10)
Series2x = Xval, IF(ParA==20)
Series2y = Yval, IF(ParA==20)
```

This way I can continue to sort however I like, and no change to the chart.  I know that I can F9 the selected data to convert to raw numbers, but I would like to be able to reuse the series selection on multiple data sets.

Does anyone know if this is even possible in Excel?

Comment: This would be pretty easy to do with a macro/VBA. If you're interested in that approach I can help.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I can't say I've used either before, so I'd be open to what you have to say.  I'm also curious if Names may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. You will have to run the macro "UpdateChart" each time you sort/re-sort the data, but this seems to be working for me.

I create some `Names` in the macro, and then set the series Values & XValues to those ranges, although that would not strictly be necessary.

[image: screenshot of "series 2" after the update macro]

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim s1xVals As Range
    Dim s1Vals As Range
    Dim s1Test As Double
    Dim s2Test As Double
    Dim nmAddress As String
    Dim nm1 As Name
    Dim nm2 As Name
    Dim parAVals As Range

    Set parAVals = GetRange("Define the ParA range?")

    Set s1xVals = GetRange("X Values?")
    Set s1Vals = GetRange("Y Values?")
    s1Test = Application.InputBox("What filter value for ParA?", "Series 1 Filter")
    s2Test = Application.InputBox("What filter value for ParA?", "Series 2 Filter")

    'Get the address of all cells matching the filter rule for series 1.'
    nmAddress = GetAddress(s1xVals, parAVals, s1Test)

    'Add the name to the workbook:'
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Srs1_XValues", RefersTo:=Range(nmAddress), Visible:=True
    'Repeat for the Y Values'
    nmAddress = GetAddress(s1Vals, parAVals, s1Test)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Srs1_YValues", RefersTo:=Range(nmAddress), Visible:=True

    'Repeat for series 2:'
    nmAddress = GetAddress(s1xVals, parAVals, s2Test)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Srs2_XValues", RefersTo:=Range(nmAddress), Visible:=True
    nmAddress = GetAddress(s1Vals, parAVals, s2Test)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Srs2_YValues", RefersTo:=Range(nmAddress), Visible:=True



    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart '## Modify as needed.'

    'remove any existing data in the chart, or modify as needed.'
    For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
        srs.Delete
    Next

    'Add the first series:'
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        srs.XValues = Range("srs1_XValues")
        srs.Values = Range("srs1_YValues")
        srs.Name = "Series 1 Name"          '## modify as needed.'

    'Add the second series:'
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        srs.XValues = Range("srs2_xValues")
        srs.Values = Range("srs2_YValues")
        srs.Name = "Series 2 Name"          '## modify as needed.'


End Sub

Function GetAddress(srsVals As Range, filterVals As Range, filterCriteria As Double)

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim c As Long: c = 1
    Dim tmpAddress As String

    For Each cl In filterVals
        If cl.Value = filterCriteria Then
            Debug.Print srsVals.Cells(c).Value
            'Create a string value of cell address matching criteria'
            If tmpAddress = vbNullString Then
                tmpAddress = srsVals.Cells(c).Address
            Else:
                tmpAddress = tmpAddress & "," & srsVals.Cells(c).Address
            End If
        End If
        c = c + 1
    Next

    GetAddress = tmpAddress

End Function

Private Function GetRange(msg As String) As Range

    Set GetRange = Application.InputBox(msg, Type:=8)

End Function
```

**REVISION**

The above method fails when returning string longer than 255 characters, not able to assign the address to a `Name` or to a series.

Here is a modified version that does not use `Names`, it merely collects the filtered scores in to an array, and uses those *values* to define the series.

Like the above solution, you would have to run it any time you change the data.

```
Sub UpdateChartNoNames()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim s1xVals As Range
    Dim s1Vals As Range
    Dim s1Test As Double
    Dim s2Test As Double
    Dim parAVals As Range

    Set parAVals = GetRange("Define the ParA range?")
    Set s1xVals = GetRange("X Values?")
    Set s1Vals = GetRange("Y Values?")

    '## Alternatively, you could set these ranges without using the inputbox:'
    'Set parAvals = Range("C2:C300")    '
    'Set s1XVals = Range("A2:A300")     '
    'Set s1Vals = Range("B2:B300")      '

    s1Test = Application.InputBox("What filter value for ParA?", "Series 1 Filter")
    s2Test = Application.InputBox("What filter value for ParA?", "Series 2 Filter")

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart '## Modify as needed.'

    'remove any existing data in the chart, or modify as needed.'
    For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
        srs.Delete
    Next

    'Add the first series:'
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        srs.XValues = GetValues(s1xVals, parAVals, s1Test)
        srs.Values = GetValues(s1Vals, parAVals, s1Test)
        srs.Name = "Series 1 Name"          '## modify as needed.'

    'Add the second series:'
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        srs.XValues = GetValues(s1xVals, parAVals, s2Test)
        srs.Values = GetValues(s1Vals, parAVals, s2Test)
        srs.Name = "Series 2 Name"          '## modify as needed.'


End Sub

Function GetValues(srsVals As Range, filterVals As Range, filterCriteria As Double) As Variant

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim c As Long: c = 0
    Dim tmpVar As Variant

    ReDim tmpVar(0)
    For Each cl In filterVals
        If cl.Value = filterCriteria Then
            'Debug.Print srsVals.Cells(c).Value'
            'Create a string value of cell address matching criteria'
            ReDim Preserve tmpVar(c)
            tmpVar(c) = srsVals.Cells(c).Value
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next

    GetValues = tmpVar

End Function

Private Function GetRange(msg As String) As Range

    Set GetRange = Application.InputBox(msg, Type:=8)

End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when it tries to add the Name to the workbook: "Run-time error '1004':   Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: You mean of my data?  Actually I can't - company proprietary and whatnot.  I was really just trying to do this to make my life a little easier, but it's looking like this may be a bit more difficult than it's worth.

Comment: Any chance you can just anonymize the data? Or, even delete all the data and just upload a blank workbook with the macro you have currently?

Comment: I figured out what the problem is, though not how to fix it. In the GetAddress function, my dataset is large enough that tmpAddress is hitting the max String size of 255 characters.  Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: @DavidK OK great. I will try to replicate that and figure out a workaround.

Comment: OK. I can replicate this. Seems to be a problem really using many non-contiguous cells...

Comment: I revised to essentially automate the "convert to values" feature. Perhaps not ideal, but it's the best I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I'm still having some bugs, but at this point I think it's past the scope of the question.  The answer you've given definitely solves my problem.  Now I just need to learn VB!