# Excel: Select data for graph

Tags: graph

To put it simple, I have three columns in excel like the ones below:

```
Vehicle  x     y 
1        10    10  
1        15    12
1        12    9
2        8     7
2        11    6 
3        7     12
```

x and y are the coordinates of customers assigned to the corresponding vehicle. This file is the output of a program I run in advance. The list will always be sorted by vehicle, but the number of customers assigned to vehicle "k" may change from one experiment to the next.

I would like to plot a graph containing 3 series, one for each vehicle, where the customers  of each vehicle would appear (as dots in 2D based on their x- and y- values) in different color.

In my real file, I have 12 vehicles and 3200 customers,  and the ranges change from one experiment to the next, so I would like to automate the process, i.e copy-paste the list on my excel and see the graph appear automatically (if this is possible).

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

EDIT: There is a similar post here: [Use formulas to select chart data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172131/use-formulas-to-select-chart-data) but requires the use of VB. Moreover, I am not sure whether it has been indeed answered.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this free online tool - [www.cloudyexcel.com/excel-to-graph/](http://cloudyexcel.com/excel-to-graph/)

[image: Chart created from excel data]